# GGTS not going to groovy code line during debug

Tags: debugging, grails, ggts

I have a problem debugging a GGTS project. When an exception is raised in a Groovy class of my project, if I click on class/line number link to go to the specific problem, I get the compiled code of my project class, instead the Groovy code.

I'm using:

- GGTS 3.6.2.RELEASE
- Groovy Compiler version 2.0.7
- Grails 2.2.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Go to Run → Debug Configurations

Select the remote application configuration being debugged.

Select the second tab named 'Source'

Now add the folder/projects containing the source code explicitly here.

I have used this approach when I encountered similar problem in Eclipse and this used to fix it for me. GGTS is Eclipse underneath.